# Where can I get a free RPC/public RPC to access Bitcoin mempool?

Tags: json-rpc, mempool

I'm interested in finding a reliable and free source that provides an RPC interface or an accessible API to retrieve information from the Bitcoin mempool. Any suggestions or recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is no "the" mempool. Every node has its own, and there is no guarantee that they're consistent with one another. So the obvious answer would be: run your own node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [quicknode.com](https://quicknode.com) to get a free RPC/public RPC to access the Bitcoin mempool.

[quicknode.com](https://quicknode.com) is a blockchain node provider that offers a free tier of service that includes access to the Bitcoin mempool.

You can find more information about QuickNode's free tier here: https://www.quicknode.com/docs/bitcoin

Hope this helps.

Irwing Tello

Answer (score 3):

There are some block explorers that will provide very limited access to their mempool, e.g. [blockstream.info](https://github.com/Blockstream/esplora/blob/master/API.md#mempool), or [mempool.space](https://mempool.space/docs/api/rest#get-mempool). I am not aware of any service that provides full access to their mempool via an API for free. The easiest and cheapest way might be to run your own node.

Answer (score 2):

Hi Developer advocate from Chainstack here.

Chainstack offers access to Bitcoin with 3 million free requests per month for developers. You can give it a try. The API you will be using probably includes "getmempoolinfo," "getrawmempool," and "getmempoolentry."

I strongly recommend using an RPC service instead of running your own node. Since no single node has all pending transactions in the blockchain, there's no significant benefit to running a node by yourself. This is simply how the blockchain operates. If you can use an RPC provider to do the job for free, there's really no point in setting up a server.

Hope it helps, happy coding.